# Reading values from a file using regex or some other parsing

Tags: c#, .net, regex, parsing

I have a file that logs values with a timestamp. I have to read a certain value after a specific time.

For example

File has

```
2013-03-03 19:08:22    car   2001 Ford
2013-03-03 19:08:27    Truck 2012 Chevy
2013-03-03 19:08:44    car 2008   Honda
2013-03-03 19:08:55    car 2011   Ford
2013-03-03 19:09:21    car 2005   Nissan
2013-03-03 19:08:29    car 2003   Cadillac
2013-03-03 19:08:32    car 2009   Jeep
2013-03-03 19:08:52    car 2007   Suburban
```

I want to read the time of the First instance of Chevy than add 40 seconds to it then read whichever Ford appears after that time.

```
So based upon the above log
First Chevy is at   19:08:27  
Add 40 seconds      19:09:07
Now Read first Ford that shows up after 19:09:07  in this case that would be one at 19:08:55
```

I am new to regex don't know for sure how to write it. Thanks

Comment: please explain in simple English not able to understand your problem

Comment: StackOverflow is not the palce to ask for solutions. Show us what you have tried, show some code samples. Only then people will help you. Otherwise chances are - you'll get downvoted. On the side note tho - i dont think it would be wise to use regex in your case.

Comment: Is this homework? Regex is really overkill from such simple file operations if it isn't.

Comment: As the description mentions that I am new to RegEx and also I didnt ask to write me the solution just some pointers to get started with.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, I **really** don't suggest you using Regex for that, but here is one you could use:

```
var data =  @"2013-03-03 19:08:22    car   2001 Ford
2013-03-03 19:08:27    Truck 2012 Chevy
2013-03-03 19:08:44    car 2008   Honda
2013-03-03 19:08:55    car 2011   Ford
2013-03-03 19:09:21    car 2005   Nissan
2013-03-03 19:08:29    car 2003   Cadillac
2013-03-03 19:08:32    car 2009   Jeep
2013-03-03 19:08:52    car 2007   Suburban";

string regex =
    @"(\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}\s+\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2})[^\n\r]+?Chevy.+?(\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}\s+\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2})[^\n\r]+?Ford";
var m = Regex.Match(data, regex, RegexOptions.Singleline);

Console.WriteLine("Chevy date: {0}", DateTime.Parse(m.Groups[1].Value));
Console.WriteLine("Ford date: {0}", DateTime.Parse(m.Groups[2].Value));
```

The above code will print:

```
Chevy date: 2013-03-03 19:08:27
Ford date: 2013-03-03 19:08:55
```

All you have to do is add 40 seconds. You can do it using the `AddSeconds(..)` method in `DateTime`.

**Edit:** The above regex explained:

- `(\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}\s+\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2})` Match some DateTime
- `[^\n\r]+?Chevy` Try to match "Chevy" in the same line
- `.+?` Match a chunk of text...
- `(\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}\s+\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2})` Until it matches some DateTime again...
- `[^\n\r]+?Ford` ...which has "Ford" in the same line

---

**Edit**: Here is another approach that doesn't require using regular expressions:

```
using (var reader = new StreamReader(@"C:\file-here.txt")) {
    bool chevyFound = false;
    while (!reader.EndOfStream) {
        var line = reader.ReadLine().Trim();

        if (chevyFound && line.EndsWith("Ford")) {
            var fordDate = DateTime.Parse(line.Substring(0, 19));
            Console.WriteLine("Ford Date: {0}", fordDate);
            break;
        }

        if (line.EndsWith("Chevy")) {
            var chevyDate = DateTime.Parse(line.Substring(0, 19));
            Console.WriteLine("Chevy Date: {0}", chevyDate);
            chevyFound = true;
        }
    }
}
```

Perhaps when someone told you you should use regular expressions, he/she meant when parsing the DateTimes (instead of doing `Substring(0,19)`). In that case, you can replace it by:

```
var chevyDate = DateTime.Parse(Regex.Match(line, "^\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}\s+\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}").Value)
```

Comment: Thanks Oscar. Why you dont suggest not using RegEx and what other solution you think I should use instead.

Comment: @J.Davidson see my edit. When I say "not using regex", I not using only a regular expression (reading line by line instead, etc.), although as you can see in my edit, you still can use regex for parsing the date.

Comment: @J.Davidson I see you posted a new question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15265237/parsing-extra-characters-from-datetime). If my answer didn't solve your problem, feel free to comment here. If it did, please, accept it as an answer.