# Parsing extra characters from Datetime

Tags: c#, .net, regex

Hi I have following code that reads the date from a file.

```
using (var reader = new StreamReader(@"C:\myfile.txt")) 
{
    bool found= false;
    while (!reader.EndOfStream) 
  {
        var line = reader.ReadLine().Trim();

        if (found && line.EndsWith("Test")) 
        {
            var fordDate = DateTime.Parse(line.Substring(0, 19));
            Console.WriteLine("Test Date: {0}", fordDate);
            break;
        }
   }
 }
```

Problem is that it gives error when date has some other text connected with it.
For example

```
\r\n2013-03-03 12:22:02
```

I am trying to change it so that code can remove "\r\n" or any other text from it and just get the date part.

Comment: Have you tried trimming the substring `line.Substring(0, 19).Trim()`

Comment: Is your code works? found value is never changed, datetime can't be parsed.

Comment: @Kane if the string starts with trimmable characters, the length of the substring will no longer be enough to hold the relevant data.

Comment: please look at my answer - we have a discussion with Robert Koritnik :) Do you realy mean "any possbile text" in you answer?

Comment: @x2. no, it doesn't. See the entire code here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15239902/reading-values-from-a-file-using-regex-or-some-other-parsing/15240495#15240495

Answer (score 3):

### You should use regular expressions

If your dates are always of the same format, you can easily write a regular expression that will extract dates from individual lines and strip anything else on each side. For the purpose of understanding regular expression should look like this:

```
\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}\s\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}
```

This regular expression is too simplified and allows dates like `0000-00-00 99:99:99` which is likely invalid. It depends whether your file can hold some values that may apear as dates, but are not. A more complex (but more valid) expression would be (assuming that date is `YYYY-MM-DD` and not `YYYY-DD-MM`):

```
[12]\d{3}-(?:0[1-9]|1[0-2])-(?:0[1-9]|[12]\d|3[01])\s(?:[01]\d|2[0-3]):(?:[0-5]\d):(?:[0-5]\d)
```

This one will allow dates from year 1000 to 2999 with correct month numbers from 01-12 and days from 01-31 and hours from 00:00:00 to 23:59:59.

But to make this regular expression more useful I'll put it in parentheses and give it a name so these dates will become part of a named capture group (`date`) in your code that you can access using its name rather than index.

```
Regex rx = "(?<date>[12]\d{3}-(?:0\d|1[0-2])-(?:0[1-9]|[12]\d|3[01])\s(?:[01]\d|2[0-3]):(?:[0-5]\d):(?:[0-5]\d)).*Test$";
if (rx.Text(line))
{
    Match m = rx.Match(line);
    // no need to use TryParse as regex assures correct formatting
    fordDate = DateTime.Parse(m.Groups["date"]);
}
```

So instead of checking manually that line ends with `Test` I've also included the same requirement in the regular expression.

Comment: See here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15239902/reading-values-from-a-file-using-regex-or-some-other-parsing/15240495#15240495

Comment: @OscarMederos: that's ok, but that's a different question with a different (although related) problem. In this question that we're answering here we're barely stripping dates of whatever other garbage.

Comment: See the last line of my answer. I was just pointing out that I already suggested him to use that regular expression. Not a big deal, it was just a comment ;)

Answer (score 1):

Use this code to replace symbols you need:

```
string lineAfterReplace = line.Replace("\t", "").Replace("\r", "").Replace("\n", "");
```

@J. Davidson - it may be also better for you to use `TryParse` [MSDN Link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/vstudio/system.datetime.tryparse.aspx)

than you have some kind of this code:

```
if (DateTime.TryParse(dateString, out dateValue))
{
   /* it was parsed without errors */
}
```

Comment: @RobertKoritnik - in J. Davidson question "when date has some other text.." it is not equal to "any". And my answer fit the examples from the question.

Comment: You should read his last line that goes: *...so that code can remove "\r\n" or **any** other text from it...*

Comment: I think he mean some kind of format for string, thats whyw \r and \t

Comment: I don't really care whether *any* means any `\s` character or any other. I don't want to assume OP's problems. I've rather written an answer that handles *any* as he wrote it. No assumptions.

Comment: And BTW: `\t`, `\r` and `\n` are already trimmed by the `Trim()` method. So because OP has asked a question it seems he was having a problem, because `Trim` wasn't sufficient. This just means that your tree replacement calls equal one trim call.

Comment: yeah it can be any text this is just one of it with \r\n

Answer (score 0):

Change:

```
var fordDate = DateTime.Parse(line.Substring(0, 19));
```

To:

```
var fordDate = DateTime.Parse(line.Substring(0, 19).Trim());
```

If Every DateTime String is alone in one line of the file it is better to use:

```
var fordDate = DateTime.Parse(line.Trim());
```